# Removing string in both sides from the column

Tags: mysql

My table contain 6 columns `(id,description,...etc)`.

Example of data from the `Description column` is:

> **Ex:** Printer **with** (abc..xyz) **is** canceled.

I want to delete the string before the "**with**" and 
after the "**is**" string.

Output should be like this

**`(abc..xyz).`**

Any idea,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: E.g.: `SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX ('Printer with (abc..xyz) is canceled.',' with ',-1),' is ',1) x;`

Comment: @Strawberry your comment should be the answer :)

Comment: @Noman The question is too trivial to warrant an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE yourTable SET description = REPLACE(description, 'Printer with', '');
```

But keep in mind this method doesn't understand regexp.